# Expanding a vertical div to the full height

Tags: html, css

I have an html page broken into 4 parts: Header, menu, content and footer.
Header is at the top, footer at the bottom. In between are the menu on the left and the content on the right.
The height of the page may be set by the menu or the content, depending on which is bigger (both can change).
I want to put a background on the menu block that extends to the footer, even if the actual menu items are much shorted. So, basically, I want the menu block to be filled in, based on the size of either it or the content, depending on which is bigger.  Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried in your question.

Comment: Ill be giving answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up the menu and content areas with `display: table-cell`:

```
//add the table div as well as the cell class to menu and content

<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell menu">menu</div>
    <div class="cell content">content</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>


.header, .footer { width: 100%; height: 50px; }
.table { display: table; width: 100%; }
.cell { display: table-cell; }
.menu { width: 50px; }
.content { }
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fd5o6c11/3)

Comment: Can you do the same by placing the footer at the bottom just as the OP asked?

Comment: The OP didn't ask for the footer to be fixed to the bottom of the window... The question asked for the page height to be determined by content or menu (whichever is larger).

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/176dgmhy/

This can not be achieved using anything but display table or javascript.

Display table-cell makes divs act like table cells but without cluttering the css with table elements like tr,td, and so on.

```
* {
    border: 1px solid;
}
header {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.cont {
    width: 500px;
}
.wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrap > * {
    display: table-cell;
}
.menu {
    width: 30%;
}
.wrap .stuff {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I liked the completeness of your answer, but the one I chose as "the answer" was all in place, so making it a little easier to read. Thank you for the time you took, however, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 :**

Use **`flexbox`**

This is an [**example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVwqgE?editors=110) of how to achieve your goal using a flebox.

---

**Method 2 :**

One way to do so would be setting -

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and then

```
div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will allow the `div` to take full height of the screen.

But the drawback of this is that if the content is too big, then it might get cut on smaller screens

Here is a [**pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqQoMw?editors=110) as an example